# Q_ASSERT breaks c++ exception handling

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I have this simple code in class method (using std::map < std::string, std::string> as container for various data):

```
 try {
    commonHeader->version = options.at("M3UA version").at(0);
  } catch (const std::out_of_range& err) {
    commonHeader->version = 1;
  }
```

And I'm using QtTest to run some tests, one particular slot having

```
Q_ASSERT(isupPage->ui->cicLineEdit == isupResultPage->ui->cicLineEdit);
```

in the end.

When this test is active, all exceptions become uncatchable, resulting in broken code and std::terminate() for thread. However, changing Q_ASSERT to QVERIFY seems to solve the problem.

Is this intended behavior for Q_ASSERT, or should I look in my code more thoroughly?

Comment: what library or code-base did you use for parsing M3UA messages ? Thanks.

Comment: @atari83, although this code is from the parser written by me, it was built on top of DSI Dialogic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Q_ASSERT` is a generic debugging macro that may indeed terminate your program under certain conditions (see also `qFatal`). `QVERIFY` is a macro to be used in tests, so that is the one you should use.